# ㄴ지 as unsure reason?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

"너무 피곤한지 옷을 입은 채 자고 있는데 깨울까요? " is translated as

He fell a sleep wearing his clothes on maybe because he is too tired. Should we wake him up?

Can the ㄴ지 form can also be used as an unsure reason?
Similar to 아/어서 그런지?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

## [-ㄴ지](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?divSearch=defViewGlobal&ParaWordNo=87429&subWordSeq=&nationCode=6&ParaNationCode=6&nation=eng&captchaNumber=&comment_user_name=&comment_title=&wordComment=&viewTypes=on&myViewWord=87430)

-nji

뒤에 오는 말의 내용에 대한 막연한 이유나 판단을 나타내는 연결 어미.

A connective ending used to indicate an ambiguous reason or judgment about the following statement.

E.g.

- 어찌나 비싼지 차마 그 물건을 살 수 없었다.
- 동생이 계단에서 넘어져 다친 건 아닌지 걱정이 되더군요.
- 집에 가는 길에 불량 청소년인지 어떤 학생이 나에게 시비를 걸었어.
- 가: 결혼한 아들 집에 다녀오셨다면서요?
- 나: 응. 우리 아들이랑 며느리가 얼마나 부지런한지 집 안이 아주 깨끗하더라고.

## [-는지](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=%EB%8A%94%EC%A7%80&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=87430&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on)

-neunji

뒤에 오는 말의 내용에 대한 막연한 이유나 판단을 나타내는 연결 어미.

A connective ending used to indicate an ambiguous reason or judgment about the following statement.

E.g.

- 동생이 내 신발을 신고 나갔는지 신발이 안 보였다.
- 다들 나가셨는지 집에 아무도 없었다.
- 외할머니께서 안 계시는지 초인종을 눌러도 대답이 없었다.
- 가: 승규 씨는 출근하셨어요?
- 나: 제가 자리에 있는지 확인해 볼게요.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)
Is ㄴ지 an abbreviation of 아/어서 그런지?

Comment: No, more like the latter is the lengthened form of the former. 아/어서 그런지 = 아/어서 그렇다(almost sure for the fact) + ㄴ지(unsure if that's the reason) ...whereas -ㄴ지 alone may indicate the speaker's unsureness about both the fact and the reasoning.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! :)